# Capacitance and energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, capacitance

So I've been reading about capacitance (Specifically in capacitors) and I'm wondering if this reasoning is sound, and why/why not:

C = Q/U

U = Q/C

We also know that:

U = E/Q

So:

E/Q = Q/C

Q^2 = EC

E = Q^2/C

However, if I try to use this it conflicts with some of the answers in my textbook, but I don't see where I made any mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The correct equation has a factor of $\frac12$ in it.

All of your calculations are correct with one important slip (It only takes one!)

You have confused the ***additional*** charge on the capacitor with the ***total*** charge on the capacitor.  Each charge that you add raises the voltage, making it harder for the next charge to get on, storing more energy.  The average charge climbs on when the capacitor is half charged...

Comment: So would the correct equation be:
E = Q^2/2C

Comment: Rotating the "missing" variable, $$E=\frac12\times Q\times V=\frac12\times C\times V^2=\frac12\times \frac{Q^2}{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $U(q)=\dfrac{dE}{dq}\implies E=\int_0^QU(q)dq$